# Should the PK on an identity column (which is surrogate key) be non-clustered?

Tags: sql-server

For a table with PK on an identity column, it will be clustered by default. Could it better be non-clustered? The PK is a surrogate key which may never be used for querying directly, it may be used to join another table.

The reason is other indexes will be created for queries. A query which uses a non-clustered index and returned columns are not covered by the index will use less LIO because there is no extra clustered index seek steps?

```
create table T (
  Id int identity(1,1) primary key, -- clustered or non-clustered?
  A ....
  B ....
  C ....
  ....)

create index ix_A on T (A)
create index ix_..... -- Many indexes can be created for different queries

select A, B 
from T 
where A between @a and @a+5 -- This query will have less LIO if the PK is non-clustered (seek)
```

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7741/when-should-a-primary-key-be-declared-non-clustered

Comment: Remember that the clustering key (field A) is included in all the other indexes + uniquefier if the index isn't unique. That can then have an affect to the size of other indexes and amount of I/O when using them

Answer (score 1):

It's perfectly fine to set your surrogate PK to be non-clustered if there is a better candidate in the table for the clustered index.

Good candidates for a clustered index are columns that you will frequently do  either range searches ([ColumnName] BETWEEN This AND That) on, or ORDER BY clauses on.

Comment: How about in a dimensional model - very rare range search. The range is performed on dimension tables after joining?

Comment: You don't have a datetime column that you might frequently be using in a range search/join?

Comment: It's like `.... from T join dimDate d1 on d1.key = T.D1Key .... where d1.Date between ....`.

Comment: Ok, well the column that you use to JOIN to a table that you will frequently do range searches on is an equally good candidate.